# incomprehensible space between elements

Tags: html, css

not able to understand why there is space between the section and article element in the below html code when all padding, margin, border are 0. ideally i thought both colors (light green and light blue) should meet in the middle but they are not. FYI browser=mozilla firefox

i also tried checking if there are default values for padding, border and margin in the browsers debugging tool and default values were present for margin. who set this default values?

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            h1      { text-align: center; }
            article { background: lightblue; }
            section { background: lightgreen; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 >testing margin</h1>
        <article>
            <h2>this is article 1</h2>
            <p>
                The placement of elements on a Web page can be fairly complicated. One of the most basic features that influence where things go on a Web page is the CSS Box Model. The Box Model governs 3 important spacing features of CSS.  We learned about margins previously as the space between elements.  There are two other similar notions, padding and borders.
            </p>
        </article>
        <section>
            <p>
                Perhaps the best way to understand is with a picture.  All elements in an html document end up being treated as rectangles somewhere in the window. The content of each rectangle corresponds to the innermost rectangle in the image below.  Just outside the content is the padding.  This is kind of like an internal margin, meaning that it separates the contents from the border.  The border essentially traces the sides of the padding rectangle.
            </p>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>

test1.html
Affichage de test1.html en cours.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your question is there are default styles for HTML elements written for browsers by browser developers. So if you haven't styled HTML elements by your own the elements gets the default browser styles.

[Default CSS Values for HTML Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp)

Answer (score 0):

`P` tag using `user agent stylesheet` so on `P` tag add below css will give you desire output. Check snippet.

```
p{padding:0; margin:0;}
```

```css
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

article {
  background: lightblue;
}

section {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<h1>testing margin</h1>
<article>
  <h2>this is article 1</h2>
  <p>
    The placement of elements on a Web page can be fairly complicated. One of the most basic features that influence where things go on a Web page is the CSS Box Model. The Box Model governs 3 important spacing features of CSS. We learned about margins previously
    as the space between elements. There are two other similar notions, padding and borders.
  </p>
</article>
<section>
  <p>
    Perhaps the best way to understand is with a picture. All elements in an html document end up being treated as rectangles somewhere in the window. The content of each rectangle corresponds to the innermost rectangle in the image below. Just outside the
    content is the padding. This is kind of like an internal margin, meaning that it separates the contents from the border. The border essentially traces the sides of the padding rectangle.
  </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to reset `user agent stylesheet`.
Every browser has a default CSS which user has to reset. `Normalize.css` is a small CSS file that provides better cross-browser consistency in the default styling of HTML elements.